# Radical Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of positive integers $n$ so that
$4 < \sqrt{n} < 10.$

The answer I have is 5 since 25,36,49,64,81 work but that's incorrect. Did I misread the question or did I miss something?

Comment: Do you want $n$ to be a perfect square? If not then any $n \in \Bbb N$ with $16<n<100$ will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $4 < \sqrt{n} < 10$ is equivalent to $16 < n < 100$ by squaring everything.  Therefore your answers are all integers between $16$ and $100$, and there are $99 - 16 = 83$ integers between $16$ and $100$.